# Overlapping in treap package from stathat?

Tags: go

According to this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/golang-nuts/x9bXQ9gKvZg) stathat uses overlapping with their [treap](http://www.stathat.com/src/treap):

> GoLLRB is great and there's no reason you should switch. We thought
>   the idea behind treaps was an elegant solution to our problem, so we
>   implemented it.  We liked the interface that GoLLRB provided, so we
>   mimicked it in our implementation.
>
> One thing we added to the treap package is to allow you to iterate
>   using an overlap function, so you can get all the keys in [3,9), for
>   example.  We use this a lot, often with a struct as the key.
>
> Patrick

I am playing with the following code and have no idea how to continue:

```
package main

import(
    "reflect"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stathat/treap"
)

func IntLess(p, q interface{}) bool {
        return p.(int) < q.(int)
}

func BucketOverlap(a, b interface{}) bool {
    return false
}

func main() {
    tree := treap.NewOverlapTree(IntLess, BucketOverlap)
    tree.Insert(5, "a")
    tree.Insert(7, "b")
    tree.Insert(2, "c")
    tree.Insert(1, "d")

    for v := range tree.IterateOverlap([]int{2,5}) {
        fmt.Printf("val: %v\n", v)
    }
}
```

let's say I want to get keys in range `[2,5]` => `[c,a]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution using [GoLLRB](https://github.com/petar/GoLLRB):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/petar/GoLLRB/llrb"
)

type Item struct {
    key     int
    value   string
}

func lessInt(a, b interface{}) bool {
    aa := a.(*Item)
    bb := b.(*Item)
    return aa.key < bb.key
}

func main() {
    tree := llrb.New(lessInt)
    tree.ReplaceOrInsert(&Item{5, "a"})
    tree.ReplaceOrInsert(&Item{7, "b"})
    tree.ReplaceOrInsert(&Item{2, "c"})
    tree.ReplaceOrInsert(&Item{1, "d"})
    //tree.DeleteMin()

    c := tree.IterRangeInclusive(&Item{key: 2}, &Item{key: 5})
    for item := <-c; item != nil; item = <-c {
        i := item.(*Item)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", i.value)
    }
}
```

Still I am wondering if this is also possible using stathat's treap.

Answer (score 1):

The first place I'd start would be the tests for the stathat treap code:
https://github.com/stathat/treap/blob/master/treap_test.go#L164

It seems that what you're doing is trying to pass a slice of keys when it is expecting a single one.  You are also trying to do vector operations (i.e. range overlap) on a value that is scalar (i.e. int).

Maybe I am misunderstanding the point of the overlap, but my understanding is that the use for it is as an interval tree:

```
key1 := []int{1, 3}
key2 := []int{2, 4}
key3 := []int{5, 6}
```

These are intervals (low and high).  key1 overlaps key2, and vice-versa.  Neither overlap key3.  In this case, the overlap would be useful (i.e. `IterateOverlap([]int{2,3})` would give me key1 and key2, whereas `IterateOverlap([]int{3,5})` would return all).

I'm not sure how you'd iterate over these entries.  Maybe this:

```
for i := 2; i <= 5; i++ {
  fmt.Printf("val: %v\n", tree.Get(i))
}
```

Again, I've not used this implementation, so forgive me if I'm barking up the wrong tree.